# How to fix 'permission denied' error in spss

Tags: spss

I'm doing an aggregate on spss and it shows error:
Error opening an SPSS Statistic System file: " file name"
permission denied (DATA1201)
I opened the file name linked and I was able to open it, I'm also sure I have the permission to write or edit data in that folder, so do you know why it shows I have no permission?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of the file on the AGGREGATE command to see if it still gives the warnings. I suspect SPSS still thinks that particular data file is open, in which case you can not overwrite an already open file.